# HOC react redux firebase. (Error: Firebase storage is required to upload files)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage, react-redux-firebase

error firebase storage is required
may be i wrong at providing the parameter to uploadFile().
please suggest correction if u see any
code:

```
export const addCategory = category => {
  return (dispatch, getState, { getFirestore, getFirebase }) => {
    const firebase = getFirebase();
    const firestore = getFirestore();

    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(category.imageFile);

    const imageExtension = category.imageFile.name.split('.')[
      category.imageFile.name.split('.').length - 1
    ];
    var imageFileName = `${Math.round(
      Math.random() * 100000000000
    )}.${imageExtension}`;

    reader.onload = e => {
      const storagePath = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/grocapp-f4eb9.appspot.com/o/";
      const dbPath = 'test';
      const fileMetadata = { contentType: 'image/jpeg' };

      firebase
        .uploadFile(storagePath, e.target.result, dbPath, { metadata: fileMetadata })
        .then(() => {
          console.log('File uploaded successfully');
        });
    };
  };
};
```

error code in the browser :

```
Error: Firebase storage is required to upload files
  19 |      const dbPath = 'test';
  20 |      const fileMetadata = { contentType: 'image/jpeg' };
  21 | 
> 22 |      firebase
  23 |^       .uploadFile(storagePath, e.target.result, dbPath, { metadata: fileMetadata })
  24 |        .then(() => {
  25 |          console.log('File uploaded successfully');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should install [`@firebase/storage`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/storage) if you haven't already and import it

[It is checked in the start of uploadFile method](https://github.com/prescottprue/react-redux-firebase/blob/master/src/actions/storage.js#L38)

```js
import "firebase/storage";
```